# Unable to archive IMAP email with GMail app

Tags: stock-email-app, imap

I'm using the Gmail app on a Pixel 2 running Android 10. I'm connecting to a private IMAP server (despite the app name, "Gmail" is a general-purpose mail client, not just for Google Mail).

**How can I get it to recognize my Archive folder?**

My IMAP server (Dovecot) offers an Archive folder, which is honored by all other IMAP clients (Roundcube, Windows 10 Mail). The Andoid Gmail app, however, does not show an archive button when reading the mail, and swiping will delete—rather than archive—the message.

When I'm reading Google Mail, it works as expected; there's an archive button next to the trash, and swiping archives the message. With my Dovecot account, the archive button isn't shown, and swiping moves it to the Trash folder.

Here's what the IMAP server returns for available folders:

```
d list "" *
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Archive) "." Archive
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "." Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Drafts) "." Drafts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "." Junk
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "." Trash
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." INBOX
d OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

This is correct, and is honored by other clients.

In the Gmail app, if I click on the hamburger menu when viewing a message, I can select "Move to", and it shows an Archive folder there (in fact, Archive is the only folder listed there). Selecting this does move it to the Archive folder. This is unworkable, though; I need the Archive button while reading, and I need swiping to archive instead of deleting.

Comment: *I need the Archive button while reading, and I need swiping to archive instead of deleting*- since you are referring to a generic mail client, have a look at [FairEmail](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/source-email-t3824168), a privacy focused mail client that can do **much, much more**

Comment: I am not familiar with other parts of your question

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @beeshyams. I like that alternative. I found a small bug in it, and the author already fixed it. The free version was good enough for me, but I'm buying it to support him.

Comment: At this point, after trying five different Android IMAP clients—all of which work fine—I can confidently say that the Gmail app is not fully implementing the folder specification. Perhaps it's intentionally crippled, but either way, it doesn't appear to be usable for my needs.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please self answer to help others in future :)